# Display tab bar in view not in tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an application that has a menu controller containing a tab bar controller and another view controller.  I would like the tab bar controller to display in my other view controller even though it's not a descendant of the tab bar.  How can I make this happen?

Comment: You can't - at least not using the structure you're describing here. What's the point of having a ViewController present a TabBar if the TabBar has no effect on the VC? Why not place the VC in the `UITabBarController`?

Comment: The tab bar contains the main functions of my application and I want them visible at all times.  This other view controller is not a main function of my application so I don't want it in the tab bar.  What they have to do now is slide the menu over and tap on the item with the tab bar to get back to it. Ideally, I want the main tab bar views always to be one tap away.